# cordova FCMplugin issuse when building android app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm to receive PUSH-messages in my cordova app (AngularJS).

When I add the plugin and build my app everything works fine.
But if I make changes to my app and build it again, I can't receive foreground-messages. (Only a problem on Android)
The plugin is still active and register the device-token for push, but the method onNotification() is no longer receiving messages.

If I remove and reinstall the plugin it works again, but only for one build.

I can't figure out what is causing the problem. 
Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I figure the "cordova build"-command somehow overwrites something but i can't figure out what

**My code for onNotification**

```
if (typeof FCMPlugin != 'undefined') {

     FCMPlugin.getToken(function (token) {
         //...
     });


     FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) {
         //...
     });


     FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
         console.log('push-message received');

         $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'test',
             template: data.message
         });

     });
 }
 else{
     console.log('FCMPlugin not available');
 }
```

Comment: would you be able to share the chunk of code which subscribes to the onNotification method.

Comment: I have added the onNotification part in the post. But I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its better you check the documentation again,[Plugin Documentation here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm#receiving-push-notification-data).
The documentation says the `onNotification` callback gives you notification `data` object which also contains `wasTapped` boolean property. Put a if-else condition on `wasTapped` property and handle property. The boolean will be `false` if the app is in foreground and notification has received and will be `true` if the app was in background and user clicked on notification.

Also make sure that you send `data` object in notification payload for FCM send api. If you are redirecting the user to other pages on clicking make sure you also send `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` in notification payload.